# How to pass parameters to a client-side HTML page, when using local files?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I am opening chrome browser from my application and passing this url then in the browser it shows as

```
file:///D:/WS/index.html%23import.html
```

Then it shows an error like "Your file could not accessed". But when I am changing "%23" to "#" it's working fine.

PS: I don't want any local server

Please help.

Comment: How exactly are you opening Chrome and passing it a URL?

Comment: So just use `#` instead? I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: I am using "#" in the url but chrome is converting it to "%23"

Comment: I am using ShellExecute from my C++ program to open the chrome